# call the ' id ' of the mysql database with varchar format but Unknown column 'GE' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I tried to call up data by 'id' format id example id = GE-DIS-001 to JOIN table with Codeigniter , the result of "Unknown column ' GE ' in 'where clause ' what's wrong ??

Controller :

```
    public function detail(){

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $detail = $this->mcrud->get_detail($id); 

    $data = array(
                'detail'=>$detail,
                'lihat' =>$this->mcrud->lihat_komentar($id),
                'isi'       =>'instrument/read_views');
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);


   }
```

Model :

```
    public function get_detail($id){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbdetail 
            JOIN tbkalibrasi ON tbkalibrasi.id = tbdetail.id
            JOIN tbsupplier ON tbsupplier.namasupplier = tbdetail.namasupplier

            WHERE tbdetail.id = {$id}
            ";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: What is there in $id ?

Comment: id is a string, its needs to be quoted

Comment: try to print your query and result you will get what is wrong.... try `print_r($sql); and print_r($this->db->query($sql)->result_array()); `

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava $id is varchar, example id GE-DIS-001

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi have been tried but still the same

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto above thing i mentioned is  does not  solve your problem but to find what where mistake will be.print the result and post them

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi , This question has been fixed , I tried adding quotes on WHERE tbdetail.id = '".$id."'"; finally running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `$id` variable contains string with spaces, so you are getting this error. Change it to

```
public function get_detail($id){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbdetail 
            JOIN tbkalibrasi ON tbkalibrasi.id = tbdetail.id
            JOIN tbsupplier ON tbsupplier.namasupplier = tbdetail.namasupplier

            WHERE tbdetail.id = '$id'
            ";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto, try to put single quotes over the `$id` variable in the query & check if it works.

Comment: have been tried . but it still does not work , I call id ( GE - DIS - 001 ) but MySQL does not read GE

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable for id missing single quotes?

```
public function get_detail($id){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbdetail 
        JOIN tbkalibrasi ON tbkalibrasi.id = tbdetail.id
        JOIN tbsupplier ON tbsupplier.namasupplier = tbdetail.namasupplier

        WHERE tbdetail.id = '{$id}'
        ";
return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
}
```